# Key steps to uploading a Drupal website from Local to live using a hosting firm

Tags: database, drupal, hosting

I'm a newbie to pushing Drupal websites from local to live via a CP panel with a hosting company and wondered if there are any key steps I need to follow? I usually end up with Internal Server 500 errors or no themes showing so not a good start!

The steps I follow are:

1. Export the database from my local PHPMyAdmin
2. Log into my hosting CP Panel and create the database on there
3. Create a user for the database (with password)
4. Change the settings.php to match the database settings
5. Load all Drupal files via FTP
6. Create a 'tmp' folder in the 'sites > default> files' directory

What am I doing wrong?! Is it something to do with the .htaccess file as to why I either get the error or my theme never shows?

Any help would be much appreciated! So stressful and frsutrating as a newbie! Once I've done 1 I'm hoping it'll be plain sailing!!

Thanks!

C

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic steps right. Check the php error logs on the server (probably accessible via the control panel if you dont have ssh access), they should give you more information as to what actually caused the 500 errors.

Doubt it is an htaccess issue unless you are doing something crazy in there.

Can you see he drupal admin at all? If so, clear cache, check watchdog for clues also.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to download and install Drupal again on the live server rather than to copy everything via FTP.  The settings.php file is where your MySQL information is stored so this file should not be copied.  Follow Drupal's documentation on how to install Drupal at https://drupal.org/documentation/install/download

To transfer your database, install and enable the Backup and Migrate module on your local server from https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate and back up your database locally.

After Drupal is installed on the live server, go ahead and copy your modules, themes, and files from /sites/all and /sites/default/files (or any non-Drupal core files that you may have created).  Enable and use the Backup and Migrate module to restore your database to your live server.  You may need to configure the php.ini file if the database is over 8MB.